# Directory Listing- Error message

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a simple website in ASP.NET application.
I don't know why, but when the page is running the browser display this message below:

Directory Listing -- /

```
Friday, December 12, 2014 09:36 PM        <dir> bin
Friday, December 12, 2014 09:38 PM        1,591 CoffeMasterpage.Master
Friday, December 12, 2014 08:48 PM          350 CoffeMasterpage.Master.cs
Friday, December 12, 2014 09:35 PM        1,431 CoffeMasterpage.Master.designer.cs
Friday, December 12, 2014 09:32 PM        <dir> Images_Coffee
Friday, December 12, 2014 08:42 PM        <dir> obj
Friday, December 12, 2014 08:42 PM        <dir> Properties
Friday, December 12, 2014 09:05 PM        <dir> Styles
Friday, December 12, 2014 08:42 PM        2,002 Web.config
Friday, December 12, 2014 08:42 PM        1,285 Web.Debug.config
Friday, December 12, 2014 08:42 PM        1,346 Web.Release.config
Friday, December 12, 2014 09:36 PM        4,719 WebTutorial.csproj
Friday, December 12, 2014 09:36 PM        1,086 WebTutorial.csproj.user
```

Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

Someone can explain to me why the browser display this message?

Comment: Your server has been configured to list files in the directory, and you either don't have a default document configured, or you didn't include one in the directory.

Comment: What Mason just said.  You don't have a default.asp, default.aspx, default.htm, default.html, index.htm, or index.html (the usual suspects) and directory browsing is not prohibited.  (Both are settings in the IIS control panel.)  That's why you instead get a directory listing.

Comment: Thanks. Do you kknow how can I fix it? year ago I wrote program in asp.net web applicatin i didn't face with this issue. I am working in visual studio 2010